# Does std::make_shared() use custom allocators?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

Consider [this code](http://ideone.com/8wO6Hc):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() {
        std::cout << "SomeClass()" << std::endl;
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
        std::cout << "~SomeClass()" << std::endl;
    }

    void* operator new(std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Custom new" << std::endl;
        return ::operator new(size);
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr, std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Custom delete" << std::endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};



int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> ptr1(new SomeClass);
    std::cout << std::endl << "Another one..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> ptr2(std::make_shared<SomeClass>());
    std::cout << std::endl << "Done!" << std::endl << std::endl;
}
```

Here is its output:

```
Custom new
SomeClass()

Another one...

SomeClass()

Done!

~SomeClass()
~SomeClass()
Custom delete
```

Clearly, `std::make_shared()` didn't call the `new` operator -- it's using a custom allocator. Is this the standard behavior for `std::make_shared()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior. From the standard (§20.7.2.2.6 *shared_ptr creation* ):

> Effects: Allocates memory suitable for an object of type T and constructs an object in that memory via the placement new expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...).`

This allows `make_shared` to allocate the storage for both the object and the data structure for the shared pointer itself (the "control block") in a single allocation, for efficiency reasons.

You could use [`std::allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) if you want to control that storage allocation.

Comment: `std::allocate_shared(const A&, Args&&...)` is also worth a mention. The first argument is the allocator to call `A::allocate` on.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Mat's correct answer, `make_shared` is typically implemented by allocating an object that contains the `shared_ptr` reference counts and a buffer of uninitialized bytes:

```
template<typename T>
  struct shared_count_inplace
  {
    long m_count;
    long weak_count;
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>::type m_storage;
    // ...
  };
```

This is the type which will be allocated on the heap, not your type, so your type's `new` is not called. Then your type will be constructed using placement `new` at the location `(void*)&m_storage`.