# Is it possible to force `std::make_shared` to use a class's new operator?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is it possible to force `std::make_shared` to use a class's new operator?  This relates to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080408/does-stdmake-shared-use-custom-allocators).  According to that question, `std::make_shared` uses a custom allocator:

> From the standard (§20.7.2.2.6 shared_ptr creation ):
>
> Effects: Allocates memory suitable for an object of type T and constructs an object in that memory via the placement new expression
>   ::new (pv) T(std::forward(args)...).

As such, I thought that I could use a custom placement new operator, but that appears to be false

```
// std::cout
#include <iostream>

// std::make_shared
#include <memory>

// Track what we're making
struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo const & foo) {
        std::cout << "Foo copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(Foo && foo) {
        std::cout << "Foo move constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo const & foo) {
        std::cout << "Foo copy assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Foo & operator = (Foo && foo) {
        std::cout << "Foo move assignment" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    void * operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
        std::cout << "Foo new" << std::endl;
        return ::operator new(size);
    }
    void * operator new(std::size_t size, void * p) throw() {
        std::cout << "Foo placement new" << std::endl;
        return ::operator new(size,p);
    }
    void* operator new (std::size_t size, std::nothrow_t const & nothrow_value) 
        throw()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo nonthrowing new" << std::endl;
        return ::operator new(size,nothrow_value);

    }
    void operator delete(void * p, std::size_t size) {
        std::cout << "Foo delete" << std::endl;
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "Foo destructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "---Creating foo" << std::endl;
    auto foo = std::make_shared <Foo> ();
    std::cout << "---Creating foo2" << std::endl;
    auto foo2 = std::shared_ptr <Foo> (new Foo());
    std::cout << "---Creating foo3" << std::endl;
    auto foo3 = std::allocate_shared <Foo> (std::allocator <Foo>());
    std::cout << "---fin" << std::endl;
}
```

which gives

```
---Creating foo
Foo constructor
---Creating foo2
Foo new
Foo constructor
---Creating foo3
Foo constructor
---fin
Foo destructor
Foo destructor
Foo delete
Foo destructor
```

Also tucked in there was an attempt to force an allocator that would call the custom new operator with the call to `std::allocate_shared`.  In any case, is there a way to make `std::make_shared` call the custom new operators without defining a whole new allocator?

Comment: Don't custom new (controlling your own allocation) and `make_shared` (not doing a 2nd allocation for your own type) have somewhat opposite goals?

Comment: Note that `make_shared` does one allocation instead of 2 for the *counting block*.

Comment: The standard text you quote specifically says  it uses `::new`, i.e. the global one not your custom one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, this is not possible (with `make_shared`).

Since a custom allocator for class `T` will typically be written and optimized (for example with a pool) to expect allocations of size `T`, and `make_shared` will be allocating *more* memory than that, I imagine it wasn't deemed an important feature to support.

Further, the standard provides `allocate_shared` for the case where you wish to use a custom allocator.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

What you do instead is create a structure containing aligned storage with a custom destroyer that cleans up the object and a bool saying if you should do so.

Then placement new the aligned storage.

Now use the aliasing shared ptr constructor to return a pointer to the aligned storage as a different type.